# Simplecov fails to exit on rspec suite completion in Ruby 2.6.3

Tags: ruby, rspec, ruby-on-rails-5, simplecov

So after upgrading the Ruby version used with my app from 2.5.5 to 2.6.3, simplecov 0.17.0 now hangs silently and permanently at the end of my test suite.

I'm running Ruby 2.6.3 and Rails 5.2.3.

As for what else may be relevant, I have capybara 3.26.0 running and I'm using RSpec.

One thing I tried is adding "use_merging false" to my SimpleCov.start block, as I saw that suggested out and about. No luck for me.

Here's an example of the output I get:

```
138 examples, 0 failures, 1 pending

Randomized with seed 29475
```

Then that's where it hangs.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Edit: SimpleCov config:

```
SimpleCov.start :rails do
  add_filter "/app/channels/"
  add_filter "/app/jobs/"
  add_filter "/app/mailers"
end
```

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov

> If you're making a Rails application, SimpleCov comes with built-in configurations (see below for information on profiles) that will get you started with groups for your Controllers, Views, Models and Helpers. To use it, the first two lines of your test_helper should be like this:

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'
```

The documenation also states:

> Load and launch SimpleCov at the very top of your test/test_helper.rb (or spec_helper.rb, rails_helper, cucumber env.rb, or whatever your preferred test framework uses):

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start
```

If this does not help, please share your simplecov entry in your Gemfile and the test-, spec-, rails_helper.

Comment: I'm all set up when it comes to that stuff, but if it helps, I'll put it in my original question.:

Just to restate the problem, Simplecov hangs after the test suite finishes.

Comment: Thanks for your configuration. I quickly tested ruby 2.6.3 with 0.17 and unfortunately cannot see the issue.